# Proxy on one SSID with OpenWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

I've bought a new Asus RT-AX53U router and installed OpenWRT.

I want to create 2+ separate SSIDs, where one (ssid_default) should work like default tunnel to net, and another one  (ssid_proxy) should use http proxy (with auth by IP).

This two should work at the same time.

What's the right way to create this?

Comment: Have you referenced the OpenWrt [Docs](https://openwrt.org/docs/start)?